# VSCode inside of HTML comment is greyed out

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes, comments

I have some lines in my HTML file commented out, but the inside of the comment is greyed out. Why is this happening?

[image: Image of comments]

The outside (`<!--` and `-->`) has a color just the inside is greyed out.

I am using the `dark-plus-syntax` theme and when using the normal theme (`dark-plus`) it does not happen.

Does it have something to do with my theme settings? I have tried to change the color of the comments but that only changes the outsides. Here are the settings:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "[dark-plus-syntax]": {
            "textMateRules": [
                {
                  "scope": [
                    "comment",
                    "comment.block.documentation",
                    "comment.block.documentation.js",
                    "comment.line.double-slash.js",
                    "storage.type.class.jsdoc",
                    "entity.name.type.instance.jsdoc",
                    "variable.other.jsdoc",
                    "punctuation.definition.comment",
                    "punctuation.definition.comment.begin.documentation",
                    "punctuation.definition.comment.end.documentation"
                  ],
                  "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#b1833d"
                  }
                }
            ]
        },
    },
```

Comment: have you looked at semantic color customization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `settings.json` I added the `comment.block.html` scope inside the `textMateRules` of the color customizations:

```
{
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "[dark-plus-syntax]": {
            "textMateRules": [
                {
                  "scope": [
                    "comment.block.html", <-- Added this
                    // Other scopes
                  ],
                  "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#b1833d"
                  }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Now the entire HTML comment is the same color.